# How to rewrite URI of custom post type?

Tags: wordpress, permalinks, custom-post-type

The site that I am working on uses the following "pretty" permalink structure:

```
http://example.com/blog/my-special-post
```

But for a custom post type my client would like to avoid having a "pretty" slug:

```
http://example.com/product/142
```

How can the post ID be used in place of the slug?

I believe that this might be possible using WP_Rewrite, but I do not know where to begin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted the same question on WordPress stack exchange site and received a good solution:

[WordPress StackExchange - How to rewrite URI of custom post type?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33551/how-to-rewrite-uri-of-custom-post-type/33555#33555)

Answer (score 0):

All of WP's posts/pages, regardless of their type, can be reached via `http://example.com/?p=foo`, where `foo` is the post ID.

By default, redirection to a "pretty permalink" takes place though.

On [the WP Codex entry for register_post_type()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) (I assume that's what you're using to set up your CPT, right?), the `rewrite` argument is described:

> rewrite
>   (boolean or array) (optional) Rewrite permalinks with this format. False to prevent rewrite.
>   Default: true and use post type as slug

So, using

```
$args = array(
    'rewrite' => false,
    // ... whatever else there is
);
register_post_type('product', $args);
```

should yield what you're looking for.

Comment: Now it is automatically redirecting to `http://example.com?p=my-special-product` instead of a numeric equivalent. Is there a way to define a custom router in WordPress? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

In the WP admin you can chane the display of the permalinks by going to 'Settings->Permalinks'. To achieve your desired results, set the custom structure to `/%post_id%/`. Unless you manually edit .htaccess and the WP rewrite rules, I don't think you can achieve a structure where you have the post slug in the URI for one post type, but the ID for another.